# R search for multiple patterns grepl

Tags: r, pattern-matching, grepl

I have below code. I want to find cells that have alphanumeric values and it should also ignore the cells that are na or NA.

How can I modify my code to that? the required R command should return below result for newcolumn

True, True, false, false, True, false, false

I tried commands 3 and 4, but they failed :(

```
> newcolumn=c(1,2,"na","NA","abc","","*")

> grepl("[[:alnum:]]", newcolumn)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

> grepl("[[:alnum:]] | na", newcolumn)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> grepl(c("[[:alnum:]]","na"), newcolumn)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
Warning message:
In grepl(c("[[:alnum:]]", "na"), newcolumn) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> grepl("[[:alnum:]]" | "na" | "NA", newcolumn)
Error in "[[:alnum:]]" | "na" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

> str(newcolumn)
 chr [1:7] "1" "2" "na" "NA" "abc" "" "*"
```

===========================update1===============================

```
newcolumn2<-newcolumn[grepl("(?=(?i)na(N)?(*SKIP)(*F))|[[:alnum:]]|(?=(?i)nan(*SKIP)(*F))|(?=(?i)null(*SKIP)(*F))", newcolumn, perl=TRUE)]
```

I updated my code as above as i want to recognize na, nan, null and their variants too. But "null part is not working. What changes should i make?

Comment: You may want to consider turning the character NA to actual `NA`  as this would make the task easier.

Comment: what is actual NA? and how do I convert NA to actual NA?

Comment: `is.na(c(1, 3, "NA", "na", NA))`  Only the last one is a true `NA`.  The other two are character.   I try not to convert them but use appropriate arguments in the `read.table` function (or what ever function you read the data in with).  Something like `read.table(file="dat.csv",  na.strings= c("999", "NA", "na"))`  See `?NA` for more on `NA`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 grepl("(?=(?i)na(*SKIP)(*F))|[[:alnum:]]", newcolumn, perl=TRUE)
 #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

`(?i)` means case-insensitive.  So it should match `na`, `NA`, `nA`, or `Na`.  `(*SKIP)(*F)` in the pattern makes the match to fail.   Now the pattern in the right side of `|` symbol ie. `[[:alnum:]]` would be the one that would be matched.

#### Update

```
 newcolumn <- c(1,2,"na","NA","abc","","*", "NaN", "nan", "nAn")
 grepl("(?i)na(N)?(*SKIP)(*F)|[[:alnum:]]", newcolumn, perl=TRUE)
 # [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: please explain how does (?=(?i)na(*SKIP)(*F)) work...the code is working and gives required result

Comment: if i want to ignore "NaN" too ...what should i do? I tried "grepl("(?=(?i)na(*SKIP)(*F))|[[:alnum:]]|NaN", newcolumn, perl=TRUE)"...but it didnt work :(

Comment: @user2543622 you should ask a new question.  This one is a month old and has been answered already